# Pointers to structures, fields changing values inexplicably

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I'm fully prepared to be told that I'm doing something stupid/wrong; this is what I expect.

I'm getting a feel for structures and coming a cropper when it comes to accessing the fields from the pointers. Code to follow.

matrix.h:

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H_INCLUDED
#define MATRIX_H_INCLUDED

#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    int* vector;
} vector_t;

#endif // MATRIX_H_INCLUDED
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "matrix.h"

vector_t* vector_new(size_t size)
{
    int vector[size];
    vector_t v;
    v.size = size;
    v.vector = vector;
    return &v;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector_t* vec = vector_new(3);
    printf("v has size %d.\n", vec->size);
    printf("v has size %d.\n", vec->size);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So this is a very simple program where I create a vector structure of size 3, return the pointer to the structure and then print its size. This, on the first print instance is 3 which then changes to 2686668 on the next print. What is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest instead to design it with creation and allocation of the structure first, and then passing a pointer to an init function that takes the pointer of the created structure, inits it and is void (modifying the members of the struct pointed to by the pointer rather than trying to create the struct within the function).

Comment: the new function is too painful... worst way to do it, it's not even maintainable. you should malloc a block instead. your problem is caused by the stack. the address you return is in the stack, however, this part of stack is use by `printf`, i.e., you data is corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable `v` from `vector_new`. This does not have a slightest chance to work. By the time `vector_new` returns to `main`, all local variables are destroyed and your pointer points to nowhere. Moreover, the memory `v.vector` points to is also a local array `vector`. It is also destroyed when `vector_new` returns.

This is why you see garbage printed by your `printf`.

Your code has to be completely redesigned with regard to memory management. The actual array has to be allocated dynamically, using `malloc`. The `vector_t` object itself might be allocated dynamically or might be declared as a local variable in `main` and passed to `vector_new` for initialization. (Which approach you want to follow is up to you).

For example, if we decide to do everything using dynamic allocation, then it might look as follows

```
vector_t* vector_new(size_t size)
{
   vector_t* v = malloc(sizeof *v);
   v->size = size;
   v->vector = malloc(v->size * sizeof *v->vector);
   return v;
}
```

(and don't forget to check that `malloc` succeeded).

However, everything that we allocated dynamically we have to deallocate later using `free`. So, you will have to write a `vector_free` function for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is basically all I needed to know to write all my functions.

Answer (score 0):

***Complete re-write*** of answer to address your question, and to provide alternate approach:

The code as written in OP will not compile:  &v is an illegal return value.

If I modify your code as such:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    int* vector;
} vector_t;

vector_t* vector_new(size_t size)
{
    int vector[size];
    vector_t v, *pV;
    pV = &v;
    pV->size = size;
    pV->vector = vector;
    return pV;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector_t* vec = vector_new(3);
    printf("v has size %d.\n", vec->size);
    printf("v has size %d.\n", vec->size);
    getchar();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It builds and runs, but returns unintended values for vec->size in `main()` due to the local scope of that variable in the function vector_new.

Recommend creating globally visible instance of your struct, and redefine `vector_new()` to `int initVector(void)`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

typedef struct
{
    size_t size;
    int* vector;
} vector_t;
vector_t v, *pV;//globally visible instance of struct

int initVector(void)
{
    int i;
    pV->size = SIZE;
    pV->vector = calloc(SIZE, sizeof(int));
    if(!pV->vector) return -1;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        pV->vector[i] = i; 
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;
    pV = &v; //initialize instance of struct
    if(initVector() == 0)
    {
        printf("pV->size has size %d.\n", pV->size);
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++) printf("pV->vector[%d] == %d.\n", i, pV->vector[i]);
    }
    getchar(); //to pause execution

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Yields these results:

[image]

You still need to write a freeVector function to undo all the allocated memory.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr - :), yes, it was.